# Brownian motion exercise

Tags: brownian-motion, gaussian

Given $Z(t)=B(t)Y$, with $B(t)$ standard brownian motion, also $t \in (0,1)$ and $Y \sim N(0,1)$. $B(t)$ and $Y$ are independent.
Compute $E[Z(t)]$ , $Var[Z(t)]$ and $Cov[Z(t),Z(s)]$ .
Prove also that $Z(t)$ is a brownian motion.
It's easy to obtain
$$
E[Z(t)]=0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ Var[Z(t)]=t
$$
Then I suppose that $t>s$ and compute

$$
Cov[Z(t),Z(s)]=E\big\{[B(t)Y][B(s)Y]\big\} =\\
=E\big\{Y^2B(s)[B(t)-B(s)]+Y^2B^2(s) \big\} = \\
E[Y^2B^2(s)]=s
$$
For a generic $s$ we get

$$
Cov[Z(t),Z(s)]=min\{t,s\}
$$

Here comes the doubt. To prove that Z(t) is also a brownian motion I have to prove the independence of the increments.
For $t>s$
$$
E[Z(t)-Z(s)]=0 \\
Var[Z(t)-Z(s)]=s
$$

To prove that generic increments are mutually independent is sufficient to prove that $Cov[Z(t)-Z(s),Z(s)-Z(0)]=0$?
Thank you for the answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You computed $\mathbb{E}(Z(t))$ , $Var(Z(t))$ and $Cov(Z(t),Z(s))$ correctly.

But what you've been asked to prove is *not* true, i.e. $Z$ is *not* a Brownian motion.
To see this, just note that $Z(t)$ is the product of two Normal random variables, so it cannot be normal.